# is there a way to use different exchange account to send out email in blue prism?

Tags: credentials, blueprism, rpa

Currently i am sending out email using MAPIEX but the sender will be referring to mine. I have an exchange account to use for this bot. How can i apply in blue prism? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAPIEx allows you to target actions to specific Outlook Profiles that are installed on the Runtime Resource executing your Process. The overarching idea here is to maintain at least one Outlook profile on each of your Runtime Resources that's tied to the bot's dedicated Exchange account that Blue Prism can leverage to send and receive messages as the dedicated account.

On each of the Runtime Resources that will need access to the bot-dedicated Exchange account, create a new Outlook profile in accordance with the associated Outlook support article ["Create an Outlook profile" (support.office.com)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-outlook-profile-f544c1ba-3352-4b3b-be0b-8d42a540459d). Configure that new profile with a unique name and with the credentials of the bot's dedicated Exchange account. When dealing with scaled processes (>1 bot requiring access), you should be naming the Outlook profile the same across them all.

Once the profile's been created on all the Runtime Resources, re-configure your "Send Mail" actions to pass the string name of the new Outlook profile in the "Profile" input field (emphasized below):

[image: Send Mail action stage configuration]